# Button Not Fully Drawn

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button with text and an image on it. It gets set up in viewDidAppear and then in the IBAction I change the Attributed title. For some reason the button background color doesn't completely cover the button on the initial draw. It leaves a horizontal sliver of white. I found that by running my formatButton function in the IBAction subsequent button presses show a properly drawn button. But I can't get the first loaded view of the button to look right. Any ideas?

I found that by formatting in the IBAction it fixed it for future button draws but a sendAction(.touchUpInside) couldn't even fake it into fixing the draw problem. (It did change the button text like the IBAction makes it though.)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    formatButton(btn: searchTitlesButton)
    formatButton(btn: searchPeopleButton)
    formatButton(btn: searchCategoryButton)
    searchTitlesButton.setTitle("Title", for: .normal)
    searchPeopleButton.setTitle("Actor", for: .normal)
    //searchCategoryButton.setTitle(categoryList[searchCategoryIndex], for: .normal)

    let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named:"DownArrow")
    let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
    fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: categoryList[searchCategoryIndex]+"   "))
    fullString.append(imageString)
    searchCategoryButton.setAttributedTitle(fullString, for: .normal)

    formatButton(btn: searchCategoryButton)

    postTableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(120)
}

@IBAction func searchCategoryButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if searchCategoryIndex < categoryList.count - 1 {
        searchCategoryIndex += 1
    } else {
        searchCategoryIndex = 0
    }
    // Going to try and make a formatted label with a string and image of a down arrow.
    let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named:"DownArrow")
    let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
    fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: categoryList[searchCategoryIndex]+"   "))
    fullString.append(imageString)
    searchCategoryButton.setAttributedTitle(fullString, for: .normal)
    formatButton(btn: searchCategoryButton)
}

func formatButton(btn:UIButton) {

    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn.layer.borderWidth = 1
    btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = btn.bounds
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(25/255.0), green: CGFloat(113/255.0), blue: CGFloat(255/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    btn.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    btn.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the background gradient doesn't fully cover the button, it probably because the size of the button changes when you set the attributed title. The best way to solve this, is by creating a subclass of `UIButton`, so that you can update the frame of your custom gradient layer, whenever the button's bounds change. For example:

```
class GradientButton: UIButton {

    private let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
        let bottomColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(25/255.0), green: CGFloat(113/255.0), blue: CGFloat(255/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            gradientLayer.frame = layer.bounds
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the storyboard of nib you can change the class of the button to GradientButton. It should now automatically apply the gradient styling, and update the frame whenever the bounds of the button change.

I hope you find this useful. Let me know if you are still having issues.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you so much!